# python, C, ctypes and a strange character

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to figure out how to use `C` functions in a `python` code. It looks like by far the simplest solution is to use `ctypes`. However for some reason I see strange behavior after I create a library which I import to python. All the details are provided below.

Here is what I have for `C` code:

```
/* mymodule.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mymodule.h"
void displayargs(int i, char c, char* s) {
  (void)printf("i = %d, c = %c, s = %s\n", i, c, s);
}

/* mymodule.h */
void displayargs(int i, char c, char* s)
```

I build a library out of it using the following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c mymodule.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmymodule.so.1 -o libmymodule.so mymodule.o
```

My Python test code looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# mymoduletest.py
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.CDLL('./libmymodule.so')
mylib.displayargs(10, 'c', "hello world!")
```

When I run ./mymoduletest.py I expect to see

```
i = 10, c = c, s = hello world!
```

however I see

```
i = 10, c = �, s = hello world!
```

Why `�` character is displayed instead of an actual `char` value of `c`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does Python have a `char` type? Or does it simply pass a string of length 1 for `c`?

Comment: What happens if you call it as `mylib.displayargs(10, 99, "hello world!")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the function's argument and return types:

```
mylib.displayargs.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char, ctypes.c_char_p)
mylib.displayargs.restype = None  # None means void here.
```

If you don't specify the types, Python has to guess, and the guess it makes when you pass a string is that the function wants a `char *`.